# Heading on first comment

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-comments

I'd like to have a header on the comment list. Is there a php if statement that I could use? Something like `<php if $first : ?>`. I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override comment-wrapper.tpl.php. Find the comment-wrapper.tpl.php from your current theme and make a copy of it in your development directory. From there you can modify it to add your header. As an illustration see below (but you need to use the comment-wrapper from your current theme).

```
<?php
// $Id: comment-wrapper.tpl.php,v 1.2 2007/08/07 08:39:35 goba Exp $

/**
 * @file comment-wrapper.tpl.php
 * Default theme implementation to wrap comments.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - $content: All comments for a given page. Also contains sorting controls
 *   and comment forms if the site is configured for it.
 *
 * The following variables are provided for contextual information.
 * - $node: Node object the comments are attached to.
 * The constants below the variables show the possible values and should be
 * used for comparison.
 * - $display_mode
 *   - COMMENT_MODE_FLAT_COLLAPSED
 *   - COMMENT_MODE_FLAT_EXPANDED
 *   - COMMENT_MODE_THREADED_COLLAPSED
 *   - COMMENT_MODE_THREADED_EXPANDED
 * - $display_order
 *   - COMMENT_ORDER_NEWEST_FIRST
 *   - COMMENT_ORDER_OLDEST_FIRST
 * - $comment_controls_state
 *   - COMMENT_CONTROLS_ABOVE
 *   - COMMENT_CONTROLS_BELOW
 *   - COMMENT_CONTROLS_ABOVE_BELOW
 *   - COMMENT_CONTROLS_HIDDEN
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_comment_wrapper()
 * @see theme_comment_wrapper()
 */
?>
<div id="comments">
  <h2>My Comment Header</h2>
  <?php print $content; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work in the beginning but then I noticed there was a mytheme_preprocess_function that used comment-wrapper. I removed it and it works now. Thanks!